# How can i get belowview which i attached in android

Tags: android

Hi am new to android I don't know the view name but i need to add that view in my android app.I attach the view below.please provide any solutions.Thanks in advance...[image]

Comment: Please give us better explanation about your problem, and what have you been trying so far.

Comment: When i click the button I need the above view (I.evideo,chat,link,quote etc).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the libary [here](https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu). I think thats what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Use [HashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html) to map each button to the view you need.